# Set figcaption width from img and align

Tags: html, css, layout, figure, figcaption

To display figures, I use

```
<figure>
  <img …>
  <figcaption>This is a longer caption that may wrap lines.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Now I'm trying to get the following via CSS:

1. `figure` is horizontally centered on the page.
2. `figcaption` has the same width as `img`. This is important for line wraps.
3. The width comes from `img`.
4. `figcaption` is left-aligned with `img`.

In other words, what I want is this (boxes for clarity):

[image: figure layout I want]

I have hacked the above mockup by giving `figure` an explicit `width` (i.e., violating 3 above), but of course that's not very desirable.

How do I get this to work? Should I look into `layout: flex`?

Answer (score 0):

min-content + flex or grid might help, display;table works too to shrink figure to the widest element.

snippet to play with below

```css
body {/* if the matter is to center on the center of the window */
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;/*or */  /* display:flex;*/  /*also works*/
  min-height: 100vh;
}

figure {
  background:yellow;
  /* center x,y*/
  margin: auto;
  /* without a flex or grid parent, make it a block that can shrink and center horizontally
  display:block; */
  
  /* shrink to the single widest content */
  width: min-content;
  /* or/and  instead  block
  display:table;
  width:0;
  */
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100">
  <figcaption>This is a longer caption that may wrap lines untill a word is wider than the image itself.</figcaption>
</figure>
```